# Spree install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

When i try to :

spree install - spree is not a rails project

When i add gem to gemfile - and try to  i rails generate spree:install

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection': ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
from /home/efectiva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spree [Github page](https://github.com/spree/spree) says this is how to add spree to an application.

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.13
gem install spree
rails _3.2.13_ new my_store
spree install my_store
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of spree, you are trying to install..??

Follow the steps as mentioned on https://github.com/spree/spree

Recommended is add spree gem to your Gemfile and run bundle install. Use stable version of Spree. 
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-0-stable'  (Add this to your Gemfile)

Just for Info -
Current version of spree(2.0.3) doesn't include Jirafe